# Как изменить стиль блока в фиксированном виде?

Tags: css

```
<div class="floatings"><div class="nofloatings">Блок</div></div>
```

nofloatings - не фиксированный блок
floating - фиксированный

.nofloating {background: white;}
.floatings {}
Что прописать в css что-бы .floating не наследовал фон именно в таком виде расположения в коде floatings ->nofloatings

Comment: А если просто прописать background-color тот, который Вам нужен для .nofloatings ?

Comment: Ничего не понял. floatings и так никогда не будет наследовать фон от nofloatings, потому что наследоваться от потомков нельзя в принципе. В чём проблема-то?

Comment: Попробовал, не сработало

Comment: @andreymal Вот сайт low-coster.ru при прокрутке вниз фиксируется поисковая форма и набор навигационных ссылок, мне необходимо что-бы ссылки в фиксированном виде были без фона

Comment: Ну так там у ссылок класс `logo` стоит, у которого белый фон. Нужно просто у этого `logo` убрать белый фон при активном `fixeds` и всё

Comment: @andreymal Вот у меня и не получается, в этом и загвоздка

Comment: `.floatings.fixeds .logo {background-color: transparent;}` — что сложного здесь?

Comment: И вообще почему у ссылок стоит класс `logo`, если ссылки — это не лого?

Comment: @andreymal Получилось. Logo - это блог логотипов авиакомпаний, но в него вошли и эти ссылки, что-бы не прописать к ним дополнительные стили, экономия кода, скорость загрузки и расположение блока. Основные причины. Оформите пожалуйста ответом, я приму.

Comment: Этот ответ не имеет никакого отношения к тексту вопроса, писать тут нечего. А вы пытаетесь экономить там, где экономить вредно

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, я приму к сведению Ваше мнение и возможно прислушаюсь. С уважением.